# recursive expansion of macros in racket?

Tags: racket

I'm wondering if there is a way to do recursive expansion of macros?

```
(define-syntax my-define
  (syntax-rules ()
   [(my-define (fn v ...) body) #'(define (fn v ...) body)]))


(define-syntax my-let
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(my-let ([v e] ...) body) #'(let ([v e] ...) body)]))

;(my-define (f1 a) a)
; this returns (define (f1 a) a)

;(my-let ([x 10]) x)
; this returns (let ([x 10]) x)

(my-define (f1 a) (my-let ([x 10]) x))
; but this returns (define (f1 a) (my-let [x 10] x)))
```

The nested case is somehow not expanded. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work fine, when you remove the `#'` (which you probably put it in to debug):

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax my-define
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(my-define (fn v ...) body) 
        (define (fn v ...) body)]))


(define-syntax my-let
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(my-let ([v e] ...) body)
        (let ([v e] ...) body)]))

(my-define (fact n)
  (my-let ([k (- n 1)])
    (if (zero? n) 1 (* n (fact k)))))

(fact 5)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Even after this is fixed the macro expander does not expand sub expressions like `my-let` in `my-define` as in definintion of `fact` has and the only workaround I have found is to disable macro hinding in the expander. This has the side effect of leaking a lot of internals. Is there a better way?